# CSRF after (enable to true) not working INSERT, ADD, DELETE

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I want to token Generate CSRF in CodeIgniter framework, so I enable csrf token changes true.

[image: Here is the image]

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
      var id = $(".data-check:checked").val();
            $.ajax({  
             url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>MasterPartTypeController/part_type_fetch_getbyid",  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{id:id},  
             dataType:"json",  
             success:function(data)      
             {  
                $('#part_type').val(data.part_type);
                $('#description').val(data.description);
                $('#id').val(id);
                $(".ui-page-toggler" ).slideToggle("slow");
                $('.ui-page-toggler').removeClass('hide');
                $('#action').val("Edit");  
             }  
        })  
    });
```

> 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is codeigniter looks in the post vars not the header. I use this code at the top of my header file:

```
            var token = {};
            token['<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>'] = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
                jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                    data: token,
                    type: 'POST',
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            alert('AJAX page not found.');
                        } else {
                            console.error('AJAX Error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                        }
                    }
                });
```